# Lisp - Splitting Input into Separate Strings

Tags: string, list, input, split, lisp

I'm trying to take user input and storing it in a list, only instead of a list consisting of a single string, I want each word scanned in to be its own string.
Example:

```
> (input)
This is my input. Hopefully this works
```

would return:

```
("this" "is" "my" "input" "hopefully" "this" "works")
```

Taking note that I don't want any spaces or punctuation in my final list.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Checkout http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/strings.html they have a bunch of common use case functions one of which is a simple space split which you could modify to remove punctuation and the like.

Comment: The Cookbook continues here: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/strings.html

Answer (score 23):

[`split-sequence`](http://www.cliki.net/SPLIT-SEQUENCE) is the off-the-shelf solution.

you can also roll your own:

```
(defun my-split (string &key (delimiterp #'delimiterp))
  (loop :for beg = (position-if-not delimiterp string)
    :then (position-if-not delimiterp string :start (1+ end))
    :for end = (and beg (position-if delimiterp string :start beg))
    :when beg :collect (subseq string beg end)
    :while end))
```

where `delimiterp` checks whether you want to split on this character, e.g.

```
(defun delimiterp (c) (or (char= c #\Space) (char= c #\,)))
```

or

```
(defun delimiterp (c) (position c " ,.;/"))
```

PS. looking at your expected return value, you seem to want to call [`string-downcase`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stg_up.htm) before `my-split`.

PPS. you can easily modify `my-split` to accept `:start`, `:end`, `:delimiterp` &c.

PPPS. Sorry about bugs in the first two versions of `my-split`. Please consider that an indicator that one should *not* roll one's own version of this function, but use the off-the-shelf solution.

Comment: I find plenty of material on split-sequence, but apparently I need to import the cl-utilities package, which I just can't figure out how to do =/
#imanewb

Comment: @SeanEvans: careful! `import` is a CL function which you do *not* want here! what you need is *install* the package using, e.g., *quicklisp*: `(ql:quickload "split-sequence")`

Comment: @sds: Your edit broke your code (for instance, test with `""` and `"a"`).

Comment: To clarify, the first code can't handle strings that end with a delimiter (e.g. `"abc "`), and the second version most of the times fails to get the last token (e.g. `"ab cd" -> ("ab")`).

Comment: I think I fixed the code now. Sorry about the bugs.

Comment: I don't know the details but I have to change delimiterp into #'delimiterp for the code to work.

Comment: This is useful. However, when I try to install "split-sequence", it seems to run successfully, but then complains that this function is unknown. What could cause this? (I am using Aquamacs with SBCL and SLIME).

Comment: Also, if one uses "my-split" function from above, is it possible to split on an empty character? That is, is it possible to do a character-by-character split?

Comment: char-by-char split is easier done by `coerce` to `list`

Comment: if you have problems installing `split-sequence`, you should ask for support from the vendor, not here. e.g., a separate question would be fine.

Answer (score 10):

For that task in Common-Lisp I found useful `(uiop:split-string str :separator " ")` and the package `uiop`, in general, has a lot of utilities, take a look at the docs https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/uiop.html#index-split_002dstring.

Comment: `uiop:split-string` is nice, but it can’t split by newline, sadly.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig I don't believe that's true. I have a text file with a bunch of newlines and was able to run `(uiop:split-string (uiop:read-file-string "input.txt") :separator uiop:+lf+)`. This returned a cons of strings, one for each line in the file.

Answer (score 5):

There's `cl-ppcre:split`:

```
* (split "\\s+" "foo   bar baz
frob")
("foo" "bar" "baz" "frob")

* (split "\\s*" "foo bar   baz")
("f" "o" "o" "b" "a" "r" "b" "a" "z")

* (split "(\\s+)" "foo bar   baz")
("foo" "bar" "baz")

* (split "(\\s+)" "foo bar   baz" :with-registers-p t)
("foo" " " "bar" "   " "baz")

* (split "(\\s)(\\s*)" "foo bar   baz" :with-registers-p t)
("foo" " " "" "bar" " " "  " "baz")

* (split "(,)|(;)" "foo,bar;baz" :with-registers-p t)
("foo" "," NIL "bar" NIL ";" "baz")

* (split "(,)|(;)" "foo,bar;baz" :with-registers-p t :omit-unmatched-p t)
("foo" "," "bar" ";" "baz")

* (split ":" "a:b:c:d:e:f:g::")
("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g")

* (split ":" "a:b:c:d:e:f:g::" :limit 1)
("a:b:c:d:e:f:g::")

* (split ":" "a:b:c:d:e:f:g::" :limit 2)
("a" "b:c:d:e:f:g::")

* (split ":" "a:b:c:d:e:f:g::" :limit 3)
("a" "b" "c:d:e:f:g::")

* (split ":" "a:b:c:d:e:f:g::" :limit 1000)
("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "" "")
```

http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/#split

For common cases there is the (new, "modern and consistent") [cl-str](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str) string manipulation library:

```
(str:words "a sentence    with   spaces") ; cut with spaces, returns words
(str:replace-all "," "sentence") ; to easily replace characters, and not treat them as regexps (cl-ppcr treats them as regexps)
```

You have [cl-slug](https://github.com/EuAndreh/cl-slug) to remove non-ascii characters and also punctuation:

```
 (asciify "Eu André!") ; => "Eu Andre!"
```

as well as `str:remove-punctuation` (that uses `cl-change-case:no-case`).

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
; in AutoLisp usage (splitStr "get off of my cloud" " ") returns (get off of my cloud)

(defun splitStr (src delim / word letter)

  (setq wordlist (list))
  (setq cnt 1)
  (while (<= cnt (strlen src))

    (setq word "")

    (setq letter (substr src cnt 1))
    (while (and (/= letter delim) (<= cnt (strlen src)) ) ; endless loop if hits NUL
      (setq word (strcat word letter))
      (setq cnt (+ cnt 1))      
      (setq letter (substr src cnt 1))
    ) ; while

    (setq cnt (+ cnt 1))
    (setq wordlist (append wordlist (list word)))

  )

  (princ wordlist)

  (princ)

) ;defun
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(defun splitStr (src pat /)
    (setq wordlist (list))
    (setq len (strlen pat))
    (setq cnt 0)
    (setq letter cnt)
    (while (setq cnt (vl-string-search pat src letter))
        (setq word (substr src (1+ letter) (- cnt letter)))
        (setq letter (+ cnt len))
        (setq wordlist (append wordlist (list word)))
    )
    (setq wordlist (append wordlist (list (substr src (1+ letter)))))
)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is always good to provide an explanation of your code and any references that may be helpful. Check out [answer] for details on answering questions.